# Java Random - always printing 1

Tags: java, random

I came across one code snippet which is using `Random` to get 10 integers. But `Random` is not returning random numbers, instead 1 always.

Code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random random = new Random(441287210);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        System.out.print(random.nextInt(10) + " ");
}
```

And I could not find explanation to this. Can anybody help to understand this behaviour?

Comment: Just to be precise - where actually is the class Random coming from?

Comment: It is returning a bunch of psudo-random numbers based on the see you gave it.  You just happened to pick a seed where there's a bunch of 1s coming up.

Comment: @Jägermeister It's just java.util.Random

Comment: why not seed it against the Calender's `getTime()` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not always. Given 441287210 as the seed, it just so happens that the next 10 random numbers between 0 and 10 turn out to be all 1s...

```
Random random = new Random(441287210);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    System.out.print(random.nextInt(10) + " ");
}
```

If you generate 100 numbers, you'll get:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 4 7 2 2 6 0 3 0 2 8 4 1 6 0 0 0 2 8 2 9 8 9 2 5 2 1 1 4 5 3 4 1 4 1 8 7 6 6 0 6 5 0 4 5 5 6 0 8 3 8 9 7 4 0 9 9 7 7 9 3 9 6 4 5 0 6 3 7 4 9 8 7 6 2 8 9 8 4 4 8 4 9 0 1 6 9 6 1 5
```

Comment: "There might even be a seed such that using it you'll get 100 times 1s, who knows?" This would then be a bad random number generator, since 10 power 100 (1 by 10 power 100 should roughly be the probability) , is much higher then the long range. while 10 power 10 is in range!

Comment: @AlexWien you're right, dropped that point